# Meteor default proxy

Tags: nginx, meteor, proxy, reverse-proxy

When a meteor app starts, the following message appears:

```
=> Started proxy.
=> Started your app.
```

I intend to use nginx as reverse proxy, but first I cannot understand which type of proxy was started, and how its configuration may be changed.

Comment: Using nginx for your production build is totally fine. What you read on the dev command line is only the proxy for the dev environment that handles the requests on your local Host.

Comment: @Jankapunkt right, but can I change the proxy of the dev environment ? At first, my intention was to set nginx even in the dev environment, so that the dev environment is as close as possible to the production environment.

Comment: The proxy mentioned is basically a parent process, which is part of the build tooling. It monitors your code, and kicks off a rebuild, restarting the main node process. Don't worry about trying to emulate production on your dev machine, because it works quite differently. Just set up a staging server and deploy to that if you want a more 'production like' environment

Comment: Thank you both :D